# Utilizar .map (Javascript) para obtener un array que contenga objetos con una propiedad "valor"

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, map

Tengo declarado el siguiente array
  const numeros = [2,11,-4,6,3,15,8];

y tengo que utilizar .map (en Javascript) para obtener un nuevo array que contenga objetos con una propiedad "valor", debiendo devolver
  [{valor:1}{valor:2}...]

He probado cosas como estas, pero me da que estoy demasiado perdido.

```js
numeros.map(function(elem) {
    const newElem = {};
    return newElem[elem.clave] = elem.valor;
});
```

```js
numeros = numeros.map(elem => ({valor:[numeros]}));
console.log(numeros);
```

```js
numeros = numeros.map(elem => ({...elem, valor:[2,11,-4,6,3,15,8]}));
console.log(numeros);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que entender que `map` es como un `for-loop` pero es una forma más declarativa de hacer el `for-loop` y el callback se ejecuta por cada item del array.
El map devuelve un nuevo array no modifica el que estas iterando.

```js
const numeros = [2,11,-4,6,3,15,8];
const numerosClaveValor = numeros.map(num => ({valor:num }));
console.log(numerosClaveValor);
```